# How can I test timed Notification? Or is my code somehow wrong?

Tags: android, android-notifications

I want to deliver timed notifications (everyday, 5:00AM), and tried to do this using AlarmManager with the following code:

```
Intent appIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        PendingIntent penIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,
                appIntent, 0);

        alarmManager.cancel(penIntent);

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
        cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, penIntent);
```

The NotificationService.class looks (at least the important parts) like this:

```
int id = 001;

            NotificationManager mNotifyMng = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                    MainActivity.this).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon).setContentTitle("Test")
                    .setContentText("Test!");

            mNotifyMng.notify(id, mBuilder.build());
            stopSelf();
```

I can't seem to get it to work. When I set the emulator clock to 4:59 or something and wait for it to change to 5:00, there is no notification showing up and I can't figure another way to test it.
I hope you know some way to test it or find the bug in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is that you cancel the `PendingIntent` but then you need to recreate it again before setting `alarmManager`.

```
  //cancel pendingIntent
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  PendingIntent penIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,appIntent, 0);   
  alarmManager.cancel(penIntent);

  //reset pendingIntent
  Intent appIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationService.class);
  AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
  PendingIntent penIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0,appIntent, 0);  
  Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 5);
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, cal.getTimeInMillis(),                                                                      
          AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, penIntent);
```

To cancel a `PendingIntent` you need to create it exactly as you did the first time then call `AlarmManager`s `cancel()` on it as you are. But then you need to create it again to set the alarm on the `PendingIntent`

> **I hope you know some way to test...

There may be a better way but, for testing purposes, I will sometimes set a global debug flag which will change times between testing and production. So say 4 hours might be 2 minutes. Times of the day may be a little more tricky but you can change the time to whatever hour, minute, or whatever is close. Once you know it is triggering at the right time then you can change it back and still test when that time of day comes around but you now know it should be working.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you tell me how to "do" your testing method? I'm really not good with the emulator. And shouldn't the pendingIntent stay the same, I thought I could use the alarmManager.canle(penIntent) to cancel any repeating alarms that may have been set before...

Comment: It won't just cancel any `PendingIntent`, it has to be recreated exactly the same as originally to cancel that `PendingIntent` in case there are others. Try it and let me know if it works. I try not to use an emulator because an actual device is much better. I simply change the times to something that is close (if it is a time of the day) or to shorter intervals if lengths of time like in my example. I hope this helps

Comment: I can't seem to find a setting that lets the time "run faster". It may be because I got your plan wrong. I installed the apk (with debuggable flag) on my device, set the time to 4:59 and waited, but nothing happend. I hope I'm not too stupid for you ;)

Comment: I'm probably not explaining myself well. For testing, I would set the alarm for like 1 minute. Then you don't have to mess with anything else...just wait a minute and see if it goes off. I don't see anything obviously wrong here so I would set a breakpoint after you set your alarmManager and make sure everything looks ok there (pendingIntent isn't null, time is set correctly, etc...) Then you know if the problem is there or possibly with the set up of the notification

Comment: I checked the variables, penIntent, appIntent and the Calendar should be fine but I can't find any Information inside of alarmManager. I don't know if this is normal or if the time should be set there? I also set it to repeat every 10 seconds, but nothing happens. I hope you have another idea

Comment: What is that flag value in your `PendingIntent`? Try using something like `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT`

Comment: Changed it, didn't seem to affect anything. The bug has to be somewhere in the alarmManager, I put some "Log.i()" stuff in my NotificationService and nothing showed up, so I dont even get there...